# Cocos2D 3.1 Xcode 4.5.2 Default project not compile

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, xcode4.5

I have Xcode 4.5.2 and I installed Cocos2D 3.1.0. When I create a project, the default code doesn't compile. I have the error ARC Semantic Issue : No visible @interface for 'CCNode' declares the selector 'wasRunning'. There is the function -(void)wasRunning:(BOOL)wasRunning in CCNode.m but it's not declared in CCNode.h. So I put it in CCNode.h or move the function in CCNode.m at the beginning of CCNode.m, and the error disappears.
Then I have another error in CCScheduler.m : 'CCScheduledTarget' does not have a member named '_paused'. As I don't want to modify a DEFAULT project like that, I gave up to ask why I have those errors in a default project and how to correct them correctly?

Comment: Not sure if cocos2d runs in Xcode 4.x at all. Maybe try with Xcode 5. Also be sure to get the latest beta which is 3.2.